# Camel JSON to XML conversion issue

Tags: xml, json, apache-camel

If I convert a JSON to XML with a default namespace using Camel unmarshal and `XmlJsonDataFormat`, all the opening xml elements have a space at the end. I didn't find an possibility to affect this behavior.

This is the converted XML:

```
<Message xmlns="http://example.com/Message/1">
    <Header >
        <Header1 >header 1</Header1>
        <Header2 >header 2</Header2>
    </Header>
</Message>
```

This is my route definition:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // create JSON to XML data format
    XmlJsonDataFormat json2XmlFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
    json2XmlFormat.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    json2XmlFormat.setRootName("Message");

    List<XmlJsonDataFormat.NamespacesPerElementMapping> namespaces = new        ArrayList<XmlJsonDataFormat.NamespacesPerElementMapping>();
    namespaces.add(new XmlJsonDataFormat.NamespacesPerElementMapping("Message", "||http://example.com/Message/1|"));
    json2XmlFormat.setNamespaceMappings(namespaces);

    from("direct:input")
        .unmarshal(json2XmlFormat)
        .log("${body}");
}
```

The converted XML is still valid with the spaces. But I would like to have a solution with out them.

`setSkipWhitespace()` and `setTrimSpaces()` are only for XML to JSON

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the result without spaces in the tags if the namespace is defined without the `|` characters (this is equivalent to no namespace):

```
namespaces.add(new XmlJsonDataFormat.NamespacesPerElementMapping("Message", "http://example.com/Message/1"));
```

Or if a proper alias for the namespace is defined such as `ns`:

```
namespaces.add(new XmlJsonDataFormat.NamespacesPerElementMapping("Message", "|ns|http://example.com/Message/1|"));
```

Comment: when I try you first suggestion, the top level element doesn't have a namespace at all.

Comment: @user3092750 Yes, that's true. If you need a namepace, stick with the second solution.

Comment: Is it possible to configure namespaces through XML? (Blueprint DSL)